# Fortigate Firewall - portrange 0

Tags: firewall, protocol

I've just stumbled upon a funny custom service definition:

```
edit "cust_serv"
    set protocol TCP
    set tcp-portrange 0 
next
```

What does tcp-portrange 0 have for a meaning to the Fortigate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set tcp-portrange 0` is specific for FortiOS and denotes 'any' port. FortiOS often uses the single zero as a token for 'any'.

Answer (score 0):

That declaration is incorrect.  the "portrange" syntax requires a range, as in something like `set tcp portrange 100-200`.  TCP port 0 is categorized as "Reserved" according to the [IANA specifications](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml).  You can define rules that would match port 0, but I know of no services that would use port 0.

Comment: I know the IANA specifications. I was rather wondering if that is a short-cut or has a special meaning for Fortigate Firewalls, after all it's their configuration file.

Comment: In all honesty, I didn't know any specifics of the type of firewall you were using.  I read the docs from their website:

http://docs.fortinet.com/fgt/handbook/cli_html/index.html#page/FortiOS%205.0%20CLI/config_firewall.10.32.html 

But there is very little info to be found there.  It looks very similar to a `lib-pcap` filter specification, which would probably just ignore the invalid declaration.  Perhaps the specification is invalid and just meant to give you an idea of the structure.